# SQL check if the value of some column is null inside a where statement and if so set it to some value

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, where-clause, isnull

I have this SQL query

```
SELECT * 
FROM   ##tempt 
WHERE  ( minstock <= 0 
         AND numitems - backorder - cstock >= 1 ) 
        OR ( minstock >= 1 
             AND numitems - backorder + minstock - cstock >= 1 )
```

How would I check if the value of `minstock` is null and if its null then set it to some number?

Comment: can try use ISNULL(minstock,0) or something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use `isnull(minstock, 0)` - it will return 0 if minstok is null.
you can also use `coalesce(minstock, other_field, 0)` for more than two values

Answer (score 1):

You cannot update the column using `UPDATE` in the same SQL query but you can use another value if a particular column's value is NULL in the database for a given row, using the `ISNULL()` function, as follows:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   ##tempt 
WHERE  ( ISNULL(minstock, 0) <= 0 
         AND numitems - backorder - cstock >= 1 ) 
    OR ( minstock >= 1 
         AND numitems - backorder + minstock - cstock >= 1 )
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * 
FROM   ##tempt 
WHERE  ( ISNULL(minstock,0)<= 0 
     AND numitems - backorder - cstock >= 1 ) 
    OR ( ISNULL(minstock,0)>= 1 
         AND numitems - backorder + ISNULL(minstock,0)- cstock >= 1 )
```